# Simple solution for instance-level Typescript decorators?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

Using the experimental decorators for Typescript, is there a simple way of adding properties to an instance of a class? I'd like to use them similar to how mixins are applied to es5-based React components.

I'm finding decorators can add properties to the class itself but they don't get applied to individual instances created with the new operator.

Comment: There are no decorators in ES7.

Comment: @Bergi There is decorator proposal, isn't it?

Comment: @madox2 Yes, it's still a proposal. It did not make it into ES7.

Answer (score 0):

Given a decorator:

```
function addPropertyTest(constructor:Function) {
   constructor.prototype.testProperty = "test";
}
```

And a class definition using this prototype:

```
@addPropertyTest
class SimpleClass {
}
```

Constructing a new instance of the class will attach the property testProperty:

```
let myClass = new SimpleClass();
console.log(`myClass.testProperty : ${(<any>myClass).testProperty} `);
```

Will output :

```
myClass.testProperty : test
```